# C# - How to change value of textbox on focus

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, textbox, onclick

I'm writing an application in C#. I would like to replace the value for the TEXT property after the user clicks (focuses) on a textbox. I would like to set the TEXT value to be blank instead of the words "ENTER NAME HERE" when they click to edit the textbox.

Front-end:

```
<asp:TextBox Text="ENTER NAME HERE" OnClick="MyTextboxID_OnClick" ID="MyTextboxID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void MyTextboxID_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    MyTextboxID.Text = "";
}
```

I tried to find the answer to this question but the answers didn't quite match what I wanted to do.

I was hoping C# had something similar to Javascript's "OnClick" or "OnFocus" events. I added the OnClick event to the textbox for illustration purposes. This OnClick event doesn't work.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply use the following `Placeholder="Enter text here."`

Option One:

```
<asp:Textbox id="txtName" runat="server" placeholder="Enter name here." />
```

Option Two:

```
$("#<%= txtName.ClientId %>").setAttribute('placeholder', 'Enter name here.');
$("#<%= txtName.ClientId %>").attr('placeholder', 'Enter name here.');
```

For the Javascript implementation, you would simply place that in your *View* and wrap it in: `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`.  Those are the ideal approaches to display text which clears on focus.

You could also utilize the `Tooltip`.  Hopefully these examples assist you.  *Important note, I have no issues with compatibility in IE 8 with the Placeholder.*  Also these approaches won't force a *Postback* which can occur due to Server-Side.  Which would force you to either do a *Postback* or implement a *Update Panel / Ajax* to hide the *Postback*.

- Plugin: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Comment: I used Placeholder successfully as well as Javascript's OnClick events (in case the browser is not compatible). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Remember that ASP.NET is primarly *server-side*. Actions that run in C# require a post-back to the server. The impact of this on a page can be mitigated somewhat by using AJAX, but this is why you don't see an "OnClick" event off the ASP control.

However, you can *still* use the Javascript "OnClick" event. Since Javascript runs on the client, and the interaction in this instance is *entirely* handled on the client, you should just use that.

Comment: Sadly, this application doesn't use any Javascript (not my idea ^_^). I was hoping I wouldn't have to use JS since, thus far, it's only "needed" in this one form. I will keep your suggestion in mind, though, since it makes perfect sense. Also, I will post back what I end up doing. Thanks!

Comment: @Gigi What's wrong with using Javascript? Its not like a library you have to include. Javascript is an element of *any* web page nowadays.

Comment: I agree with you. JS is almost indispensable nowadays. Thankfully, I was able get permission to implement a Javascript library in the application. Accomplishing this using just C# seemed unnecessarily complex. As suggested, I used Javascript's OnClick events to get this functionality done.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not comfortable using Javascript, you might want to look at [TextBoxWatermark](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx)  server side control.

It is available [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit).

```
<asp:TextBox OnClick="MyTextboxID_OnClick" 
    ID="MyTextboxID" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>

<ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TBWE2" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="MyTextboxID"
    WatermarkText="ENTER NAME HERE"
    WatermarkCssClass="watermarked" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the place holder attribute and not have to worry about replacing the text at all.  This would show when the text box is empty but disappear on focus

Comment: Good suggestion. This doesn't necessarily answer the question, so I would try to address that. Also `placeholder` has some compatibility issues (especially pre IE 10): http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp